# Проблема с триггерами в голосовом помощнике

Tags: python, триггер

Делаю голосового помощника на базе школы, есть две проблемы.

1. Помощник банально не видит литеры классов, попробовал заменить их на "бы", "вы", но всё равно не особо помогло, попробовал поменять порядок слов, но тут появилась вторая ошибка
2. Помощник говорит расписание не того класса, так как, видимо, даёт приоритет дню недели.

Например: говорю: "Максим, скажи расписание 6Б класса в понедельник", помощник говорит расписание 5Б в понедельник.

```
import config
import stt
import tts
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import datetime
from num2t4ru import num2text


print(f"{config.VA_NAME} (v{config.VA_VER}) готов к работе ...")


def va_respond(voice: str):
    print(voice)
    if voice.startswith(config.VA_ALIAS):
        # обращаются к ассистенту
        cmd = recognize_cmd(filter_cmd(voice))

        if cmd['cmd'] not in config.VA_CMD_LIST.keys():
            tts.va_speak("Что?")
        else:
            execute_cmd(cmd['cmd'])


def filter_cmd(raw_voice: str):
    cmd = raw_voice

    for x in config.VA_ALIAS:
        cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

    for x in config.VA_TBR:
        cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

    return cmd


def recognize_cmd(cmd: str):
    rc = {'cmd': '', 'percent': 0}
    for c, v in config.VA_CMD_LIST.items():

        for x in v:
            vrt = fuzz.ratio(cmd, x)
            if vrt > rc['percent']:
                rc['cmd'] = c
                rc['percent'] = vrt

    return rc


def execute_cmd(cmd: str):
    if cmd == 'help':
        # help
        text = "Я умею: ..."
        text += "произносить время ..."
        text += "рассказывать анекдоты ..."
        text += "говорить расписание"
        tts.va_speak(text)
    elif cmd == 'ctime':
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        text = "Сейч+ас " + num2text(now.hour) + " " + num2text(now.minute)
        tts.va_speak(text)
    elif cmd == '5_а_пн':
        text = "русский,география"
        tts.va_speak(text)
    elif cmd == '5_а_вт':
        text = "литература, русский, математика, география, биология"
        tts.va_speak(text)
    elif cmd == '5_а_ср':
        text = "математика, история, физ-ра, английский язык, русский язык"
        tts.va_speak(text)
    elif cmd == '5_а_чт':
        text = "литература, математика, русский язык, изо, английский язык, физ-ра"
        tts.va_speak(text)
    elif cmd == '5_а_пт':
        text = "технология, технология , английский язык, математика, история,русский язык"
        tts.va_speak(text)    
    elif cmd == '5_б_пн':
        text = "русский язык, математика, изо, история, математика"  
        tts.va_speak(text) 
    elif cmd == '5_б_вт':
        text = "музыка, изо"
        tts.va_speak(text) 

# начать прослушивание команд
stt.va_listen(va_respond)
```

сам config :

```
VA_NAME = 'Максим'

VA_VER = "2.0"

VA_ALIAS = ( 'макс', 'максим', 'максимка', 'максимум' )

VA_TBR = ('скажи', 'покажи', 'ответь', 'произнеси', 'расскажи', 'сколько', 'расписание','расписанию',)

VA_CMD_LIST = {
    "help": ('список команд', 'команды', 'что ты умеешь', 'твои навыки', 'навыки'),
    "ctime": ('время', 'текущее время', 'сейчас времени', 'который час'),
    "5_а_пн":('у пятого ','а', 'класса в понедельник'),
    "5_а_вт": ('у пятого','а','класса', 'во вторник'),
    "5_а_ср": ('у пятого','а','класса', 'в среду'),
    "5_а_чт": ('у пятого','а','класса', 'в четверг'),
    "5_а_пт": ('у пятого','а','класса', 'в пятницу'),

    "5_б_пн": ('у класса', 'пять', 'бы',),
    "5_б_вт": ('у пятого', 'бы', 'класса', 'во вторник'),
}
```